# How to use thread in C using MingW compiler

Tags: c, multithreading

I was building an own library, and I wanted to ask - given the library -, how to put two functions in different threads... Like, in the following code, I want megalovania(); to be in a thread, and the three sansf to be in another, how do I do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "ASLib.h"


int main()
{
    megalovania();
    sansf("it's a beautful day outside. birds are singing, flowers are blooming...");
    sansf("on days like this, kids like you...");
    sansf("should be burning in hell.");

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The marked duplicate is somewhat old and the subject might be worth revisiting as the answer now may differ.   A more recently maintained pthreads library for Windows is available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/pthreads4w/ for example.

Comment: How do I install it?

Comment: That is a new and different question - you need to post a new question.  However, if you do not need to make your code portable to POSIX systems or are not already familiar with pthreads, then you may as well use the Windows thread API directly.  However the answer is you don't "install" it - it is a library, you either build it or link one of the prebuilt libraries in the distribution.  Start by reading the README file.  If none of that makes any sense, you really do need to post a new question.